# Ansible pass arguments with conditions

Tags: shell, ansible

I am running a script in ansible playbook and want to pass arguments to a script. One of the argument is like

```
if {application}==tc143 then {isLive}==Yes or {isLive}=={isLive}
```

This is how my playbook looks:

```
name: run script 
shell: sh deploy.sh "{{ application }}" "{{ deployer }}" "{{ recipients_list }}"  "{{ isLive }}"
```

How can I write it in the playbook?

Comment: Your question is lacking context, but I would say: `"{{ 'Yes' if application == 'tc143' else isLive }}"`.